# Не могу правильно обратиться к дочернему объекту Unity3D / C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток)

Делаю панель выбора уровня для игры, и тут столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу обратиться к элементам которые мне нужны.

[image: Вот такая вот иерархия в этом меню]

Немного расскажу что да как:
LevelSelect -контейнер для хранения всех уровней. level_N  - панель некоторого уровня , которая содержит в себе картинку , текст и 3 серые звезды(картинки). Каждая из звезд содержит в себе еще по картинке с золотой звездой.

Теперь ближе к сути - скрипт весит на контейнере "LevelSelect" и при запуске находит все уровни, которые изображены на сцене. Но после я не могу обратиться к каждой отдельной звезде и выключить на ней компонент GoldenStar.

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

```html
      levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("level's");

      foreach(GameObject level in levels)
        {
                GameObject star_1 = GameObject.Find("Star_1");
                Transform goldStar_1 = star_1.transform.Find("GoldenStar");
                goldStar_1.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
```

Comment: `Find` - это плохо. Лучше в родительском скрипте храните список дочерних элементов, чтоб по дереву элементов бегать не пришлось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так делать (FindGameObjectsWithTag / Find / GetComponent) - плохо. Луче внесите все уровни (компоненты) в массив и обращайтесь от туда.
Конкретно по вашему коду:

```
levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("level's");

    foreach (GameObject level in levels)
    {
        foreach (Transform childs in level.transform)
        {
            if (childs.name.Contains("level_"))
            {
                Transform goldStar_1 = childs.Find("GoldenStar");
                goldStar_1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Так работать будет, но это "плохой" вариант решение вашей задачи.
Правильный вариант:

```
 public GameObject[] LevelOneGoldenStar;
public GameObject[] LevelTwoGoldenStar;
public GameObject[] LevelThreeGoldenStar;

private GameObject[][] _allLevelGoldenStars;

/// <summary>
/// Функция по изменению состояния звёзд
/// </summary>
/// <param name="level"> Уровень минус один (На 1 уровень нужно отправлять 0) на котором нужно изменить состояния GoldenStar </param>
/// <param name="enable"> Новое состояние </param>
/// <param name="starNum"> Какую именно звезду отключить, по умалчанию - все </param>
public void ChangeStarsState(int level, bool enable, int starNum = -1)
{
    if (level < 0 || level >= _allLevelGoldenStars.Length)
    {
        Debug.Log("Wrong level value");
        return;
    }


    if (starNum != -1)
    {
        if (starNum < 0 || starNum >= _allLevelGoldenStars[level].Length)
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong starNum value");
            return;
        }
        _allLevelGoldenStars[level][starNum].SetActive(enable);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _allLevelGoldenStars[level].Length; i++)
        {
            _allLevelGoldenStars[level][i].SetActive(enable);
        }
    }

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    _allLevelGoldenStars = new[] { LevelOneGoldenStar, LevelTwoGoldenStar, LevelThreeGoldenStar };
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, тогда просто объявляю в каждом уровне (Скажем level_1) по массиву со звездами а там уже через этот массив работать с ними , все верно ?

Comment: Верно, можно, для удобства поместить в двухмерный или масив масивов, я пример написал

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы ещё не знакомы с азами обращения к разным объектам в Unity.
Начнём с того, что это:

```html
      levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("level's");

      foreach(GameObject level in levels)
        {
                GameObject star_1 = GameObject.Find("Star_1");
                Transform goldStar_1 = star_1.transform.Find("GoldenStar");
                goldStar_1.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
```

Должно быть записано примерно вот так:

```html
      levels = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("level's");

      foreach(GameObject level in levels)
        {
                GameObject star_1 = GameObject.Find("Star_1");
                Transform goldStar_1 = star_1.transform.GetChild(0);
                goldStar_1.SetActive(false);
        }
```

Также не забудем о том, что такая команда, как `GameObject.Find()` выполняется не очень эффективно, и её следует заменять другими командами:

Используйте `Transform.GetChild(int Номер_Ребёнка)` для обращения к дочерним объектам. Номер считается сверху вниз от нуля(!).

Используйте `Transform.parent` для обращения к Родителю какого либо объекта.

Используйте `.transform` за место `.GetComponent<Transform>()`, иначе эта запись не верна также, как использование `.GetComponent<GameObject>()` вместо `.gameObject`.

Comment: Спасибо, да, местами не хватает знаний , спасибо за объяснение. Очень полезная информация